# How to pass multiple options to `tune2fs -E mount_opts`?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

According to the manual:

```
mount_opts=mount_option_string
                      Set  a  set  of  default mount options which will be used when the file
                      system is mounted.  Unlike  the  bitmask-based  default  mount  options
                      which  can  be  specified with the -o option, mount_option_string is an
                      arbitrary string with a maximum length of 63 bytes, which is stored  in
                      the superblock.
```

If I try to set a single option, it works:

```
$ tune2fs -E mount_opts=data=writeback /dev/sde2
tune2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
Setting extended default mount options to 'data=writeback'
```

But if I try to set multiple options, it seems to conflicts with `tune2fs` own parsing mechanism:

```
$ tune2fs -E mount_opts=data=writeback,noatime /dev/sde2 
tune2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)

Bad options specified.

Extended options are separated by commas, and may take an argument which
    is set off by an equals ('=') sign.

Valid extended options are:
    clear_mmp
    hash_alg=<hash algorithm>
    mount_opts=<extended default mount options>
    stride=<RAID per-disk chunk size in blocks>
    stripe_width=<RAID stride*data disks in blocks>
    test_fs
    ^test_fs
```

How to pass a string with multiple options on 'mount_opts'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Thomas says, `sparated by commas` is for extended option separation. However, `mount_opts` option separation is also done using `,` (see Linux kernel `fs/ext4/super.c:parse_options()`), and as of this answer `e2fsprogs`' `mke2fs` *and* `tune2fs` fail to semantically distinguish one from the other.

A [mail exchange with Theodore Y. Ts'o reveals](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/7/1068):

> Yes, this is a shortcoming in tune2fs.

There is no syntax to achieve this using the common `ext` manipulation tools. Ts'o instead advises to use `debugfs` as a workaround:

> You can set extended mount options using debugfs:
>   `debugfs -w -R "set_super_value mount_opts foo,bar" /dev/sda1`

In this case, you would need `debugfs -w -R "set_super_value mount_opts data=writeback,noatime" /dev/sde2`, but **this doesn't have the effect you expect**.

Upon mounting, the `ext4` kernel module will complain about an `Unrecognized mount option "noatime" or missing value`; in fact, it is only possible to specify `ext`-specific options, and `noatime` is not (see same kernel source file, the available options are listed in the `tokens` array). The functionally closest match is **`lazytime`**.

So, use `debugfs -w -R "set_super_value mount_opts data=writeback,lazytime" /dev/sde2`.

Answer (score 0):

The `sparated by commas` relates to the different extended options like `clear_mmp`, `hash_alg`, `mount_opts` etc.

So the correct syntax would be as follows.

```
tune2fs -E mount_opts="data=writeback noatime" /dev/sde1
```

Comment: While this doesn't error, it doesn't result in the options being applied automatically at next mount. I don't think spaces are equivalent to commas when parsing mount options. The `debugfs` solution worked for me.